# Autofac xml configuration for generic service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a class `BaseRepository<T>` which implements `IRepository` and a class called Customer.

I've a binding specified as

```
builder.RegisterType<BaseRepository<Customer>>().As<IRepository>();
```

How can i move this binding to xml configuration using Autofac.

This is what I've tried:

```
<component 
    type="MyProject.BaseRepository, MyProject"
    service="MyProject.IRepository, MyProject">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="connectionString"
            value="MyConnectionString" />
    </parameters>
</component>
```

The parameter is used for passing the consructor parameter. Actually i have parameter in the constructor of the baserepository

Comment: <component type="MyProject.BaseRepository, MyProject" service="MyProject.IRepository, MyProject"><parameters>
 <parameter name="connectionString"                        value="MyConnectionString" />
 </parameters>
</component>

The parameter is used for passing the consructor parameter. Actually i have parameter in the constructor of the baserepository.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "components": [{
    "type": "MyProject.BaseRepository, MyProject",
    "services": [{
      "type": "MyProject.IRepository`1[[Customer, mscorlib]], MyProject"
    }]
  }]
}
```

More read:http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html